# why is arrowBackground transitioning instantly and doesnt take 0.5s

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

```js
//* Define variables and html elements

const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
const arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow');

//* Add event listeners

sidebar.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  arrow.style.transitionDelay = '0s';
  sidebar.style.transitionDelay = '0.05s';
})

sidebar.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  arrow.style.transitionDelay = '0.05s';
  sidebar.style.transitionDelay = '0s';
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  width: 80px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 0;
}

.arrow {
  position: relative;
  left: 7.5px;
  right: 7.5px;
  top: 7.5px;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  fill: rgb(115, 151, 162);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 2;
}

.arrowBackground {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 82px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid rgb(50, 50, 50);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar:hover {
  width: 240px;
}

body:has(.sidebar:hover) .arrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  left: 167.5px;
}

body:has(.sidebar:hover) .arrowBackground {
  left: 160px;
}
```

```html
<section class="sidebar">
  <div class="icons">
    <div>
      <svg class="icon arrow" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path d="M9.4 233.4c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.8 0 45.3l160 160c12.5 12.5 32.8 12.5 45.3 0s12.5-32.8 0-45.3L109.2 288 416 288c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32l-306.7 0L214.6 118.6c12.5-12.5 12.5-32.8 0-45.3s-32.8-12.5-45.3 0l-160 160z"/></svg>
      <div class="arrowBackground"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

when i hover over the side bar the arrow and sidebar take 0.5s to transition but the arrow background class does it straight away and i dont know why and i want to it to take 0.5s to transition but i dont know how i would fix it

i tried rearranging some code but nothing worked at all and i tried setting the transition delay in javascript but that still didnt work

Comment: It looks like the issue is with the .arrowBackground class not having the transition property set in the default styling. To fix this, you can add the transition property to the .arrowBackground class and set it to all 0.5s ease just like the other two classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `left: 0;` to `arrowBackground` otherwise it doesn't know what it's transitioning from

```js
//* Define variables and html elements

const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
const arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow');

//* Add event listeners

sidebar.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  arrow.style.transitionDelay = '0s';
  sidebar.style.transitionDelay = '0.05s';
})

sidebar.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  arrow.style.transitionDelay = '0.05s';
  sidebar.style.transitionDelay = '0s';
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  width: 80px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 0;
}

.arrow {
  position: relative;
  left: 7.5px;
  right: 7.5px;
  top: 7.5px;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  fill: rgb(115, 151, 162);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 2;
}

.arrowBackground {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 82px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid rgb(50, 50, 50);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar:hover {
  width: 240px;
}

body:has(.sidebar:hover) .arrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  left: 167.5px;
}

body:has(.sidebar:hover) .arrowBackground {
  left: 160px;
}
```

```html
<section class="sidebar">
  <div class="icons">
    <div>
      <svg class="icon arrow" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path d="M9.4 233.4c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.8 0 45.3l160 160c12.5 12.5 32.8 12.5 45.3 0s12.5-32.8 0-45.3L109.2 288 416 288c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32l-306.7 0L214.6 118.6c12.5-12.5 12.5-32.8 0-45.3s-32.8-12.5-45.3 0l-160 160z"/></svg>
      <div class="arrowBackground"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```